# show that $L = \{a^n b^m | m\neq n\}$ is context free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

show that $L = \{a^n b^m | m\neq n\}$ is context free language using closure under union

My attempt is

- show L1 = a^n b^m n>m is context free and
- show L2 = a^n b^m n less than m is also context free

Then we know L1 U L2 = {a^n b^m m!=n }is also context free

My question is I dont know how to show L1 and L2 is context free

Comment: What does $b^n$ mean? What is $m$?

Comment: sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $L_1 = \{ a^n b^n b b^* \}$, $L_2 = \{ a^* a a^n b^n  \}$.

It is straightforward to write a CFG for $L_k$, for example:

> $L_1 \to A P$, $A \to a | a A$, $P \to \epsilon | a P b$.

Comment: This is what I usually say when I am showing a short explanation for multiple choice, Usually I will say L1 equal to that and L2 equal to that, and assume they are both CF, but L1 U L2 is not.

Comment: But I don't know how to explain they are CF individually

Comment: Write a context free grammar for them.

Comment: so as long as I can define a context free grammar, that will be enough to prove that L1 and L2 are both CF?. That should be easy

Comment: By definition, a context free language is a language that can be generated by (any suitable) context free grammar.